# Advance User Interface with OpenCV

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opencv, user-interface

I am looking for advanced user interface with OpenCV.

I have searched and got mostly using Qt, wx widgets, fltk but not with Visual Studio. 
I use Visual Studio as compiler, can I make a UI with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 ways to do it in my opinion:

1. Use the EmguCV wrapper for .NET. It will let you use all OpenCV function with all the functionnality of .NET and the Winform GUI.
2. Use the [NuGet wrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCV/) for .NET and use whatever Winform or WPF.

Maybe there is other possibility in the C++ world, but the easiest is to go with C# and .NET

Comment: Don't worry and have fun! If it works for you, don't forget to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark. Thanks!